# Segmenting a feature class based on the geometry of a multipart feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, multipart, singlepart

I have a single feature class representing tree canopy over the span of several cities. I want to segment it so that I can calculate the percentage of canopy per census tract. I'm using ArcMap 10.7.1

In other words, I'd like to use the census tracts feature class to "cookie cutter" the single part canopy layer so that I can view it tract by tract. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is it! Tabulate Intersection gave me what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Tabulate Intersection](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/tabulate-intersection.htm) tool

> Computes the intersection between two feature classes and cross-tabulates the area, length, or count of the intersecting features.